# Can I get to level 60 in the first playthrough of Mass Effect?

Tags: mass-effect

Can I reasonably get to level 60 on the first playthrough of Mass Effect?

I'm happy to complete all the non-renegade side missions.  I don't want to grind through tasks that aren't mission related just to level up.

Or will I have to start a second playthrough?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you cannot.  You are limited to a level of 50 in the first playthrough. The level cap will be raised to 60 subsequent playthroughs.  Reaching level 60 will require more than one playthrough regardless since there is not enough experience to go from level 1 to 60 in 1 playthrough.

If you do not mind loading in someone else's save files, there is a [nice site](http://www.masseffectsaves.com) that allows you to choose the storyline options and completion % for ME2 import.

You will be able to change the look and class of your imported character in ME2.

Comment: As yx_ says: note that you are experience-limited as well, you really need to start the 2nd playthrough at or near level 50 to reach 60 on the next playthrough; I finished a playthrough at level 37, and even after completing every possible sidequest in the game, I was only level 58 going into the final fight. Those last 10 levels need a *huge* amount of XP.

Comment: @M. Travis Volker - The website is legit. As to whether it is still being updated and/or tended to however...

Comment: @Raven Dreamer - Is it relevant to the question?  I don't think it is.  Not even remotely.

Comment: @M. Travis - yx_ answered your question, extrapolated why you asked the question, and provided a hypothetical solution to that as well. I fail to see the problem in a thorough answer.

Comment: yes, one of the goals here is to potentially answer any future questions of someone who has something similar to ask as yours, which is why I included that here.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it.  Thanks for the answer yx_.  I've accepted the answer.

Comment: 'mass effect saves' actually thought it was some sort of charity or something :P